# trim and fade in/out video and audio with avconv (or different tool)

Tags: video, ffmpeg, avconv, video-editing, trim

I'm using `avconv` for trimming and converting videos. Let's say I want to drop the first 7 and last 2.5 seconds of the video stream and one audio stream of an one-hour `mts` file:

```
avconv -i input.mts -map 0:0 -map 0:3 -ss 0:0:07 -t 0:59:50.5 out.mov
```

This works so far, but now I want to add two seconds of fading in and out at the beginning and the end by adding:

```
-vf fade=type=in:start_frame=350:nb_frames=100 -vf fade=type=out:start_frame=178750:nb_frames=100
```

Those frames are calculated with the 50 fps that `avconv` reports for the video source. But there is neither fading in nor out.

1) What goes wrong with the video fading and how to do it right?
2) How to add audio fading. There seems to be an `-afade` option. but I don't find it documented.

Alternatively, you can propose a different tool for this goal (trim and fade video and audio), preferrably available as package for Debian 8.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally found the time to try the answer suggested by @Mario G., but it seemed extremely cumbersome. I need to do this many dozens of times. I read the documentation of `ffmpeg` and found it much more powerful than `avconv`, including fading for audio and video, so the solution is

```
ffmpeg -i input.mts -map 0:0 -map 0:3 -ss 0:0:07 -to 0:59:57.5 -vf 'fade=t=in:st=7:d=2,fade=t=out:st=3595.5:d=2,crop=out_h=692' -af 'afade=t=in:st=7:d=2,afade=t=out:st=3595.5:d=2' out.mov
```

So the `st=` and `d=` parameters for the fade take times in seconds, no need for converting to frames.

I also discovered the `-to` option to take the end time directly instead of calculating the length.

This command does all steps

- channel selection with `-map`,
- trimming with `-ss` and `-to`,
- video fading with `-vf` option `fade=t=in` and `fade=t=out`,
- audio fading with `-af` option `afade=t=in` and `afade=t=out` and
- cropping with `-vf` option `crop=`

in a single step.

Comment: Seems convenient. Could you explain the individual parameters, please?

Comment: I added which parameter does what. For more detail, the `ffmpeg` documentation is the best source.

Comment: Thank you. I think this is the a great solution as no multiple commands and no generation of auxiliary data is required.

Answer (score 1):

**Trim:**

```
ffmpeg -i input.mts -ss 00:00:20.0 -c copy -t 00:00:30.0 output.mkv
```

Seek 20 seconds -(i)n input.mkv (and discard, by default) let it play for 30 seconds and discard everything else from there. So you've got a 30 seconds video.

**Fade**

First you need to create an image for your fades. Probably a single *.png image, full white or full black depending on your taste. In the same resolution your video was recorded, preferably.

```
ffmpeg -r 1/2 -i black.png -c:v libx264 -r 50 -y -pix_fmt yuv420p fade2s.mkv
```

This means, fade 2 seconds (-r input:1 / 2 x 50 frames per second = 100 fps). For the image info you can check The Gimp or ImageMagick. *Now you've got your fade effect.*

**Fade In:**

```
ffmpeg -i fade2s.mkv -y -vf fade=in:0:50 fade_in.mkv
```

Fade in from 0 to 50 frames (1 second - 50fps)

**Fade In + Out:**
Take the last input as your fade in and add some fade out

```
ffmpeg -i fade_in.mkv -y -vf fade=out:120:50 fade_in_out.mkv
```

Done.

Comment: Three of our children were in the hospital the last days, so I wasn't able to check your solution. But I trust you and reward the bounty. I'll come back after I find the time. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you again, mainly for leading me to use `ffmpeg` instead of `avconv`. I found an `ffmpeg`-solution now.